# The number of entities returned by this export request has exceeded the maximum allowed taleo

Tags: oracle, web-services, wsdl, enterprise, taleo

I am attempting to fetch data from Taleo Enterprise SOAP API

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:itk="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2011/05/management"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>
<itk:getLargeDocumentByKey><messageKey>124110901</messageKey>
</itk:getLargeDocumentByKey></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

and I get an error *the number of entities returned by this export request (787026) has exceeded the maximum allowed (100000).*

```
------=_Part_99112_1948897443.1507649297078
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <soap.xml@xfire.codehaus.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
<ns1:getLargeDocumentByKeyResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2011/05/management">
<ns1:Document xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2004/11/xmlmime" ns2:contentType="text/xml; charset=UTF-8">
<Include xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:1507649297078209382008132646@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
</ns1:Document></ns1:getLargeDocumentByKeyResponse></soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
------=_Part_99112_1948897443.1507649297078
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <1507649297078209382008132646@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema>

<Document xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2011/05">
<Attributes><Attribute name="count">0</Attribute>
<Attribute name="duration">0:00:00.790</Attribute>
<Attribute name="mode">T-XML</Attribute>
<Attribute name="version">http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01</Attribute></Attributes>
<Content><ExportErrors><Error>
<Code>ServerError</Code><Subcode>itk:ExportTooManyRecords</Subcode>
<Reason>The number of entities returned by this export request (787026) has exceeded the maximum allowed (100000).</Reason></Error></ExportErrors>
</Content></Document>
------=_Part_99112_1948897443.1507649297078--
```

Is there any way to split or limit of the export. Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You may need to add a filter to your results. For example, if I wanted to export offers that had an AcceptedDate: `<quer:filterings><quer:filtering><quer:isNotNull><quer:field path="AcceptedDate"/></quer:isNotNull></quer:filtering></quer:filterings>`